# Definition of encoding an alphabet

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coding-theory

I'm taking a basic course on code theory and the first definition given is the one for encoding an alphabet.

> Given an alphabet of origin $\mathcal A=\{a_1, a_2, ..., a_m\}$ and a
> code alphabet $\Sigma = \{b_1, b_2, ..., b_q\}$ encoding the alphabet
> of origin is giving an injective mapping
>
> $$c:\mathcal A \rightarrow \mathcal P (\Sigma)$$

This definition doesn't make sense to me as if you were to take the binary code alphabet $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$ then the only elements the mapping could take you to would be $\mathcal P (\Sigma)=\{\{1\}, \{0\}, \{1,0\}, \emptyset\}$ and this is not enough to encode in binary.

Another point that bothers me, is that this way the order of the elements isn't taken into account.

Wouln't a propper definition be:

> Given an alphabet of origin $\mathcal A=\{a_1, a_2, ..., a_m\}$ and a
> code alphabet $\Sigma = \{b_1, b_2, ..., b_q\}$ encoding the alphabet
> of origin is giving an injective mapping
>
> $$c:\mathcal A \rightarrow \mathcal \Sigma^n$$

This way you give each element of $\mathcal A$ a n-touple $c(a_i)=(b_1^i, b_2^i ,...b_n^i)$

Comment: Check with your lecturer. You're right the second is the normal definition.

Comment: I would have expected $\Sigma^*$ …

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen what's $\Sigma$*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so you can have either block codes (fixed length codes) with output alphabet $\Sigma^n,$ or variable length codes with output alphabet $\Sigma^\ast$ where all possible finite length strings are codewords:
$$
\Sigma^\ast = \{ \lambda\} \bigcup  \Sigma \bigcup  \Sigma^2 \cdots 
\Sigma^n \cdots.
$$
Here $\lambda$ denotes the empty string.